# Junit and EasyMock Servlet testing

Tags: java, servlets, junit, easymock

I have a problem with testing Servlet. Bouncer is a Servlet with simple method doPost and init overrited by me. But when i run that code i get exception

```
@Before
        public void Before() throws IOException, ServletException,
                InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
                IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException,
                NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, ClassNotFoundException {
            encoder = EasyMock.createMock(Encoder.class);
            EasyMock.expect(encoder.encode("password")).andReturn("asdf");
            EasyMock.expect(encoder.encode("nic")).andReturn("asss");
            EasyMock.expect(encoder.encode("Password")).andReturn("ass");
            EasyMock.replay(encoder);
            db = EasyMock.createMock(UserDataBase.class);
            db.connect();
            EasyMock.expect(db.isConnected()).andReturn(true);
            EasyMock.expect(db.getUserByLoginAndPassword("login", "asss"))
                    .andReturn(null);
            EasyMock.expect(db.getUserByLoginAndPassword("login", "asdf"))
                    .andReturn(new User("Rafal", "Machnik"));
            EasyMock.expect(db.getUserByLoginAndPassword("fake", "asdf"))
                    .andReturn(null);
            EasyMock.expect(db.getUserByLoginAndPassword("login", "ass"))
                    .andReturn(null);
            EasyMock.replay(db);

            lsf = EasyMock.createMock(LoginServiceFactory.class);
            EasyMock.expect(lsf.getEncoder()).andReturn(encoder).anyTimes();
            EasyMock.expect(lsf.getUserDataBase()).andReturn(db).anyTimes();
            EasyMock.replay(lsf);

            config = EasyMock.createMock(ServletConfig.class);
            EasyMock.expect(config.getInitParameter("LoginServiceFactory"))
                    .andReturn("pl.to.cw4.LoginServiceFactory");
            EasyMock.replay(config);

            request = EasyMock.createMock(HttpServletRequest.class);
            EasyMock.expect(request.getParameter("login")).andReturn("login")
                    .anyTimes();
            EasyMock.expect(request.getParameter("password")).andReturn("password")
                    .anyTimes();
            EasyMock.replay(request);

            pageSource = new StringWriter();

            response = EasyMock.createMock(HttpServletResponse.class);
            EasyMock.expect(response.getWriter())
                    .andReturn(new PrintWriter(pageSource)).anyTimes();
            EasyMock.replay(response);

            bouncer = new Bouncer(lsf);

            bouncer.init(config);

        }

        @Test
        public void bouncerTest() throws ServletException, IOException {
            bouncer.service(request, response);
            assertNotNull(pageSource.toString());

        }
```

java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Unexpected method call getMethod():
    at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:32)...

If someone had idea how to fix it I will be thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that the easymock has come across a method call getMethod() in a mocked object . Debug the program line by line and add a expect call for the mocked object.

You don't have to add the method call in expect if it not a mocked object but all the calls in a mocked object should be added to your test method.

getMethod() is called in the service and since you are mocking HttpServletRequest , you also need to mock all the methods call on HttpServletRequest

Answer (score 1):

The `service()` method calls `getMethod()` on the request to determine if it must call `doGet()`, `doPost()` or the other servlet methods. Since you didn't stub this call to `getMethod()` on your mock request, EasyMock throws this exception.

Why don't you call `doPost()` directly, rather than calling `service()`, since that's the method you want to test?

Comment: I didn't call directly doPost() because it by default protected and my tests are in other package ;)

Comment: Ok, now it is ok I changed it to public so I Can do it directly thank's for help ;)

Comment: It's a conventional practice to put tests in the same package as the tested class. You could also make the method public. If you don't want to do that, then you'll have to stub all the methods called internally by the service method.